# Could Javacard version be upgraded?

Tags: smartcard, javacard, jcop

I have NXP javacard.
Could Javacard version be upgraded on unlocked smartcard?
And how to do it, could it be done via GlobalPlatform?

Comment: Java Card implementations offer a runtime environment for a (programmable) smart card. I think closing this as off topic is rather harsh. I presume that running applications on a different JRE would be **on topic**.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it yourself. It will require personalization tools and new JCOP binary files. Contact NXP support and buy a new card with latest java card version.